# JPA / Hibernate orphan removal using joining entity

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

First off, I've done a lot of research on this and have not found this example yet, so I'm hoping the answer is not "re-design your database".

Using Spring and JPA (and hibernate) to delete one entity, and have it's references (or "orphans"?) automatically deleted too.

Here is the error:
**The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_ItemContainer_Item". The conflict occurred in database "MyDatabase2", table "dbo.ItemContainer", column 'itemId'.**

Here is the scenario:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Item")
public class Item implements java.io.Serializable {

  private Integer itemId; //Auto Genenerated Unique ID
  private String item; //Item description
  private Set<ItemContainer> itemContainers = new HashSet<ItemContainer>(0); //Set of ItemContainers

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "item", orphanRemoval = true)
  public Set<ItemContainer> getItemContainers() {
    return this.itemContainers;
  }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ItemContainer")
public class ItemContainer implements java.io.Serializable {

  private Integer itemContainerId; //Auto Genenerated Unique ID
  private Item item; //Item link
  private Container container; //Container link

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "itemId")
  public Item getItem() {
    return this.item;
  }

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "containerId")
  public Container getContainer() {
    return this.container;
  }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Container")
public class Container implements java.io.Serializable {

  private Integer containerId; //Auto Genenerated Unique ID
  private String container; //description
  private Set<ItemContainer> itemContainers = new HashSet<ItemContainer>(0);

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "container", orphanRemoval = true)
  public Set<ItemContainer> getItemContainers() {
    return this.itemContainers;
  }
}
```

**A Container and an Item can both exist exclusivity.** 
**An ItemContainer can only exist containing references to existing Items and Containers**

What I want to do is be able to delete an item, and have it's corresponding ItemContainer rows dropped (using orphan removal). Any Containers should still exist.

Here is how i'm trying to remove an Item:

```
@Override
public void delete(Item item) {
  EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
  em.remove(em.contains(item) ? item: em.merge(item));
}
```

I'm aware that I may have to remove the ItemContainers manually first, however I've been following guides and helps to try and get automatic orphan removal working, and would like to see it through.

Any help is appreciated.

Cheers,
Steve.

**EDIT 1:**
As JB requested: Here is the relevant code being used.

The request is coming from a jsp to

```
/deleteItem?itemId=${item.itemId}
```

It may be worth mentioning, I'm attempting to do the same in my jUnit tests (I can post the test code and any relevant classes if need be), however I do not receive the error (it passes without throwing a FK constraint error, but the ItemContainer table still contains a reference to the deleted Item).

Item Controller, Service and Dao Implementation:

```
@Controller
public class ItemController {

  @Autowired
  private ItemsService itemsService;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/deleteItem")
  public String deleteItem(@RequestParam() int itemId) {

    itemsService.delete(itemId);

    return "redirect:systemSettings/items";
  }
}

@Service("itemsService")
public class ItemsService {

  @Autowired
  private ItemsDAO itemsDao;

  public void delete(int itemId) {

    itemsDao.delete(itemsDao.getItem(itemId));
  }
}

@Repository
@Transactional
@Component("itemsDao")
public class ItemsDAOImpl implements ItemsDAO {

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  @Override
  public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return entityManager;
  }

  @Override
  public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
  }

  @Override
  public Item getItem(int itemId) {
    String queryString = "SELECT i FROM Item i "
        + "LEFT JOIN FETCH i.itemMachines "
        + "WHERE i.itemId=:itemId";
    Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(queryString);
    query.setParameter("itemId", itemId);

    Item item = (Item) query.getSingleResult();
    System.out.println(item.getItemMachines().size());

    return item;
  }

  @Override
  public void delete(Item item) {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    em.remove(em.contains(item) ? item : em.merge(item));
  } 
}
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:189)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:155)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:519)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:478)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:272)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29.delete(Unknown Source)
    at com.home.myproject.service.ItemsService.delete(ItemsService.java:45)
    at com.home.myproject.service.ItemsService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$788e7765.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:640)
    at com.home.myproject.service.ItemsService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$296a7299.delete(<generated>)
    at com.home.myproject.controllers.ItemController.deleteItem(ItemController.java:121)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3400)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3630)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:77)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:515)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_ItemContainer_Item". The conflict occurred in database "MyDatabase2", table "dbo.ItemContainer", column 'itemId'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
    ... 64 more
```

Cheers.
Steve.

**Edit 2:**

Found this question [JPA Cascade remove orphans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17018302/jpa-cascade-remove-orphans) - James' answer confirms what JB is saying, still no idea why it wont work though :(

Comment: That should work, thatnks to cascade = ALL. orphanRemoval has nothing to do with that scenario. orphanRemoval tells Hibernate to delete an ItemContainer when you remove the ItemContainer from its item. Post a complete example reproducing the problem, and the complete stack trace of the exception. My guess is that the set of ItemContainers of the Item you're deleting doesn't actually contain all the ItemContainers of the Item.

Comment: Added stack trace and code, also put a print out in itemDao.getItem() to check if the set contains the correct info, it correctly prints out "1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIRST THOUGHT (turns out to be wrong, check edit for solution)**

OK so i've gotten to the bottom of this problem.

Let me first put some context on the solution (And problem as i'm still a little confused).

The POJOs in my project are created from reverse engineering the database into java (using the hibernate tools plugin in eclipse).

This took a lot of trial and error, but got it working in the end.

The generated POJOs contained the `CascadeType.ALL` annotation.

The reason why it wasn't working?

The ItemContainer table's foreign keys did NOT have the setting to cascade deletes (despise generating the annotation in the Java).

[image]
(picture is what I followed from Google, its not my picture ;) )

Setting the two foreign keys to cascade delete through MS SQLServer Management Studio fixes the problem. I can now delete an Item and have it correctly remove ItemContainer records that link them.

**EDIT 1:

------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

Figured I'd update this since new information has come to light.

The cascade database option acctualy cercumnavigates the problem, instead of hibernate doing the cascade, the database is doing it.

**This is not correct!!!**

The culprit to this problem is actually interaction between service and DAO layers. My DAO is a Transactional class, where as my Service is not (after much research it seems common place to have it the other way around).

This is my function

```
public void delete(int itemId) {

  itemsDao.delete(itemsDao.getItem(itemId));
}
```

**Notice:**
 1. Service requests Item from DAO
 2. DAO returns Item to Service
 3. Service passes Item to DAO

Adding `@Transactional` to this method (or removing it entirely from DAO and putting it service class) fixes the problem.

The reason behind this (from my understanding) is that @Transactional informs the persistence engine to persist (or keep) its data. As soon as an entity drops outside of the @Transactional scope, it's flushed (or potentially flushed), thus, the item that gets passed back to DAO is no longer present in the entity manager (forgive me if my terms are inaccurate).

I'm hoping this is the actual solution this time ;)